# Issues with a SurfaceView when reopening app after locking and unlocking phone

Tags: java, android

In my game, I have a thread. This thread is paused in `onPause()` in the activity and restarted in `surfaceCreated` in the main game class.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  if(gt == null) {
    gt = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
    gt.setRunning(true);
    gt.start();
  }
}
```

The onPause(called from game):

```
public void onPause(){
  ... other stuff
  if(gt != null){
    try {
      gt.setRunning(false);
      gt.join();
      gt = null;
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But for some reason, when the screen is locked and unlocked, the thread does not start again. When I open the list of recent apps and reopen the app from there, the thread restarts.

Why is this happening, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your thread in `onStart()`, not in `surfaceCreated`, because the surface is not recreated in this case (your activity is not destroyed), so the method `surfaceCreated` is not called when you unlock your phone. However, `onStart()` is.